# mongodb sharded collection will not moveChunk to another shard not master

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I have having problems getting my mongodb data to actually balance between my shards.  I set up the shards and everything looks find in the sh.status() I get...

```
--- Sharding Status ---
  sharding version: {
        "_id" : 1,
        "version" : 3,
        "minCompatibleVersion" : 3,
        "currentVersion" : 4,
        "clusterId" : ObjectId("524490036b0d452cd76aea51")
}
  shards:
        {  "_id" : "shard0000",  "host" : "mongo1:27018" }
        {  "_id" : "shard0001",  "host" : "mongo2:27018" }
  databases:
        {  "_id" : "admin",  "partitioned" : false,  "primary" : "config" }
        {  "_id" : "test",  "partitioned" : false,  "primary" : "shard0000" }
        {  "_id" : "activeTvs",  "partitioned" : true,  "primary" : "shard0000" }
                activeTvs.duid
                        shard key: { "duid" : 1 }
                        chunks:
                                shard0000       11
                        { "duid" : { "$minKey" : 1 } } -->> { "duid" : "2DCAMPY4ZUR4I" } on : shard0000 Timestamp(1, 1)
                        { "duid" : "2DCAMPY4ZUR4I" } -->> { "duid" : "BDCN4UQJ3V3OA" } on : shard0000 Timestamp(1, 13)
                        { "duid" : "BDCN4UQJ3V3OA" } -->> { "duid" : "EXCN4UQJ3TLTC" } on : shard0000 Timestamp(1, 15)
                        { "duid" : "EXCN4UQJ3TLTC" } -->> { "duid" : "JHCN4UQJ3BSH2" } on : shard0000 Timestamp(1, 16)
                        { "duid" : "JHCN4UQJ3BSH2" } -->> { "duid" : "KLCN4UQJ35RCO" } on : shard0000 Timestamp(1, 11)
                        { "duid" : "KLCN4UQJ35RCO" } -->> { "duid" : "MTCN4UQJ3SH2O" } on : shard0000 Timestamp(1, 12)
                        { "duid" : "MTCN4UQJ3SH2O" } -->> { "duid" : "P7CN4UQJ3TLFU" } on : shard0000 Timestamp(1, 17)
                        { "duid" : "P7CN4UQJ3TLFU" } -->> { "duid" : "RLCN4UQJ3QELM" } on : shard0000 Timestamp(1, 18)
                        { "duid" : "RLCN4UQJ3QELM" } -->> { "duid" : "U7CN4UQJ3SQ6G" } on : shard0000 Timestamp(1, 19)
                        { "duid" : "U7CN4UQJ3SQ6G" } -->> { "duid" : "ZPCN4UQJE6DWK" } on : shard0000 Timestamp(1, 20)
                        { "duid" : "ZPCN4UQJE6DWK" } -->> { "duid" : { "$maxKey" : 1 } } on : shard0000 Timestamp(1, 4)
```

The problem is that all the data is setup on 1 shard only. i tried to set up movechunk with
sh.moveChunk("activeTvs.duid", { "duid": "JHCN4UQJ3BSH2" }, "shard0001")

and this is the output...

```
mongos> sh.moveChunk("activeTvs.duid", { "duid": "JHCN4UQJ3BSH2" }, "shard0001")
{
        "cause" : {
                "cause" : {
                        "note" : "from execCommand",
                        "ok" : 0,
                        "errmsg" : "not master"
                },
                "ok" : 0,
                "errmsg" : "moveChunk failed to engage TO-shard in the data transfer: not master"
        },
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "move failed"
}
```

I dont know how to solve this "not Master" error for the chunk migration. 
Ive been spending a lot of time on this and really need to get data to be distributed between the shards to increase the write performance.  All help is greatly appreciated thank you

Oh and i also looked into the db locks to find more info, but this is all i see

```
db.locks.find().pretty()
{
        "_id" : "configUpgrade",
        "process" : "ipaddress:27017:1380225027:1804289383",
        "state" : 0,
        "ts" : ObjectId("524490036b0d452cd76aea4f"),
        "when" : ISODate("2013-09-26T19:50:27.567Z"),
        "who" : "ipaddress:27017:1380225027:1804289383:mongosMain:846930886",
        "why" : "upgrading config database to new format v4"
}
{
        "_id" : "balancer",
        "process" : "ipaddress:27017:1380225024:1804289383",
        "state" : 0,
        "ts" : ObjectId("52449d596787fa8abc8a0311"),
        "when" : ISODate("2013-09-26T20:47:21.880Z"),
        "who" : "ip:1380225024:1804289383:Balancer:846930886",
        "why" : "doing balance round"
}
{
        "_id" : "activeTvs.duid",
        "process" : "ipaddress:27018:1380225875:1148973287",
        "state" : 0,
        "ts" : ObjectId("52449d5e46aced87c407d472"),
        "when" : ISODate("2013-09-26T20:47:26.608Z"),
        "who" : "ip:1380225875:1148973287:conn4:1169675271",
        "why" : "migrate-{ duid: MinKey }"
}
```

Comment: I have this exact problem.